# If i click the button nothing happens but it should print Hello World

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

If I click the button (Pushme) then it should as test print Hello World! but it doesn't work. Any tips?

```
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
    from PyQt5 import uic
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

    class Main(QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self):
            super(Main, self).__init__()
            uic.loadUi("Youtubedownload.ui", self)
            self.show()
            self.setWindowTitle("YoutubeDownloader")
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("download.ico"))

            self.Convertbutton.clicked.connect(self.Open_SecondWindow)

        def Open_SecondWindow(self):
            secondwindow = SecondWindow()
            secondwindow.Youtube_text.setText(self.Youtubelink.text())
            secondwindow.__init__()
            self.close()

    class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(SecondWindow, self).__init__()
            uic.loadUi("Youtubedownload_loading.ui", self)
            self.show()
            self.setWindowTitle("YoutubeDownloader")
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("download.ico"))

            self.Pushme.clicked.connect(self.Convert)


        def Convert(self):
            print("Hello World!")

    def main():
        app = QApplication([])
        window = Main()
        app.exec_()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: What is `Pushme`? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Thats my button to start the converting but that does not work either so I tried with print but that doesn't work...

Comment: According to your code, the second window shouldn't even appear (or will be closed almost instantly) since `secondwindow` is local an gets garbage collected. Also, explicitly calling `__init__` is not only unnecessary, but also **wrong**. And only classes and constants should have capitalized names, not variables, attributes or functions (see the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: Ooh can you fix it maybe that it will work?

Comment: normally you would use `self.secondwindow` instead of `secondwindow` to fix it but it seems you close first window and it may destroy this variable - so you may need to use `global secondwindow` inside `Open_SecondWindow`

Answer (score 0):

You assign window to local variable so `garbage collector` removes window at once (when it finishs function `Open_SecondWindow`) and you simply can't see it.

You have to use `self.secondwindow instead of` secondwindow` to fix it.

BTW: you shouldn't run manually `.__init__()`

---

Minimal working code - so everyone can copy and test it

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit
#from PyQt5 import uic
#from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.convert_button = QPushButton('Second Window', self)   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
        self.convert_button.move(10, 10)

        self.youtube_link = QLineEdit("???", self)
        self.youtube_link.move(10, 50)

        self.show()
        
        self.setWindowTitle("YoutubeDownloader")
        #self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("download.ico"))

        self.convert_button.clicked.connect(self.open_second_window)

    def open_second_window(self):  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
        self.second_window = SecondWindow()
        self.second_window.youtube_text.setText(self.youtube_link.text())
        self.close()

class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.pushme = QPushButton('Push Me', self)   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
        self.pushme.move(10, 10)
        
        self.youtube_text = QLabel("?", self)
        self.youtube_text.move(10, 50)
        
        self.show()
        
        self.setWindowTitle("YoutubeDownloader")
        #self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("download.ico"))

        self.pushme.clicked.connect(self.convert)

    def convert(self):  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
        print("Hello World!")

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Main()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)